# How to check if list variable exists in python mako template?

Tags: python, mako

Assuming I have the following in my template:

```
% if not mydict['somekey'] is UNDEFINED:
    ${mydict['somekey'][0]['hellothere']}</td></tr>
% endif
```

My issue is the above does not work as `mydict['somekey']` is always an array, but it could be empty. I want to be able to check to make sure that if `mydict['somekey']` is defined, I can add a check to make sure either 1) the list size is greater than 0 (from inside the template) or if the `mydict['somekey']` has elements in it so that I can print out what is in `mydict['somekey'][0]['hellothere']` when available.

What must I do? I keep getting an:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

with the above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) recommends:

> For sequences, (strings, lists, tuples), use the fact that empty
>   sequences are false.

So really you don't need to check the length and just check it like this:

```
% if mydict.get('somekey'):
    ${mydict['somekey'][0]['hellothere']}</td></tr>
% endif
```